# Element Name within a List in R that contains Brackets

Tags: r, list

I have a list and need to assign a name to an element within that list that happens to contain brackets, but I need to do this without converting the name to a quoted string.  For example:

```
    try = list()
    try[[1]] = list(beta[1,1]=1.74)
```

which would result in

```
   > try
   [[1]]
   [[1]]$beta[1,1]
   [1] 1.74
```

However, I can't figure out how to do this in R without converting the name to a quoted string

```
    try[[1]] = list('beta[1,1]'=1.74)
```

which results in

```
   > try
   [[1]]
   [[1]]$`beta[1,1]`
   [1] 1.74
```

Any help would be appreciated.  I hope what I'm trying to do is possible.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Brackets (and commas) are not syntactically valid names, as far as R is concerned, hence the back ticks are necessary.

Comment: You should explain why you want to do this.